# Добавить глазик для просмотра пароля

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть поле EditText куда я ввожу пароль. Хочу добавить туда глаз, который будет при клике на него показывать пароль.
Видел несколько библиотек для подобной реализации, но не хочу их использовать.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать другим способом более толково.
Пробовал добалять параметр `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` но выбивало ошибку мол нету в пакетах доступного варианта.

Моё поле для ввода пароля:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно использовать `EditText` не из SDK, а из библиотеки поддержки *support:design*:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       ...
       app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
          android:inputType="textPassword"
       .... />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Данная функция доступна начиная с библиотеки поддержки версии 24.2.0

Comment: Отдельно отмечу, что `TextInputEditText` должен обязательно быть обернут в `TextInputLayout` - иначе не работает

Comment: Спасибо, использовал EditText... в этом и был корень проблемы.